# Foltest the Steel-Forged King Card Bug?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm playing *The Witcher 3* and whilst trying to collect all the cards I ran into this problem:

[image: The Game Board]

This is the current game board. As you can see the other player has a Siege card that is worth 10.

This is my King Card, Foltest the Steel-Forged, which has the ability to "Destroy your enemy's strongest Siege **unit(s)** if the combined strength of all his or her Siege units is **10 or more."**

[image: Foltest The Steel Forged: "A beautiful day for battle"]

And I can't play the card for some reason (I haven't played it yet either). Is this a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure you haven't played the leader card already? The small crown in a circle next to your leader card in the first image indicates that it is not available to play. See image below of a game where the leader card is available:

[image: The game board with available leader card]

Otherwise, if you are sure that your leader card hasn't been played the other possibility is that the Nifgaardian empire leaders card has canceled your leaders ability.

This would make it impossible for you to play your leader's card at any point in the match. There would've been a message at the beginning of the match informing you that this was the case.

Comment: The cancel ability has a [different face](https://thewitcher3.wiki.fextralife.com/Nilfgaardian+Empire+Leader+Cards). I'm glad you mentioned that possibility though because that was my first thought when I read the question.